# Two overlapping ListBoxes. Selection problem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, itemspaneltemplate

I'm trying to display shapes in two separate Listboxes occupying the same space. I've set the Background to both Transparent and {x:Null} but the mouseclick is still getting captured by the topmost Listbox so I can't select any shapes from the underlying ListBox.

Here is some sample code reproducing the problem.

```
<Grid>
    <!-- ListBox 1 -->
    <ListBox Background="{x:Null}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="{x:Null}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="10"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        1
    </ListBox>

    <!-- ListBox 2 -->
    <ListBox Background="{x:Null}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="{x:Null}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="100"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="100"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="10"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        1
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

---

This is how I solved this problem for now but I'm more than open for other suggestions :) I enabled hittesting on the Grid and disabled it for both ListBoxes. Then I did the hittesting in the event handler instead

```
<Grid MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown"
      IsHitTestVisible="True"
      Background="Transparent">

    <!-- ListBox 1 -->
    <ListBox Background="Transparent"
             IsHitTestVisible="True"
             ..>
    </ListBox>

    <!-- ListBox 2 -->
    <ListBox Background="Transparent"
             IsHitTestVisible="True"
             ..>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Event handler and hittesting

```
private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = sender as Grid;
    Point ptCurrent = e.GetPosition(grid);
    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(grid, null, new HitTestResultCallback(HitTestCallback), new PointHitTestParameters(ptCurrent));
}
public HitTestResultBehavior HitTestCallback(HitTestResult htrResult)
{
    ListBoxItem listBoxItem = GetVisualParent<ListBoxItem>(htrResult.VisualHit);
    if (listBoxItem != null)
    {
        listBoxItem.IsSelected = true;
        return HitTestResultBehavior.Stop;
    }
    return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
}
public T GetVisualParent<T>(object child) where T : Visual
{
    DependencyObject c = child as DependencyObject;
    while ((c != null) && !(c is T))
    {
        c = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(c);
    }
    return c as T;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you have all the shapes in a single listbox?  It seems really unlikely that the two-listbox approach will ever get you what you want.

Comment: That's my last out.. I'm dispalying items on top of a map and they don't share the same data at all so that's why I'm using two ListBoxes. The ItemsSource is DataTables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind multiple sets of data to a single ListBox by using a CompositeCollection as the items source:

```
<ListBox ...>
  <ListBox.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
      <CollectionContainer Collection={Binding ...}" />
      <CollectionContainer Collection={Binding ...}" />
    </CompositeCollection>
  </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

You can then use data templates to control the appearance of different data types. You can either use implicit data templates or you can use an [ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx).

For more information about using and binding to a CompositeCollection, see this resource: [How do you bind a CollectionContainer to a collection in a view model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446699/how-do-you-bind-a-collectioncontainer-to-a-collection-in-a-view-model)

Answer (score 0):

You could bind your ListBoxes to a Visibility variable.  This way you can make the bottom box visible when you are in a situation where the bottom one would be selected and the top on collapsed and visa verse when you need the top one to be selected.

Comment: The problem is that both of my ListBoxes are visible all the time, thanks anyway