# same view with different viewmodel -prism

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm not sure how to describe my scenario in the title, so forgive me for the bad title.

My scenario:

MainView:

```
 <Grid>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
                SelectedIndex="0">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl x:Name="SamplesContentControl"
                                Content="{Binding View}"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

MainViewModel:

```
public  class MainViewModel
{
   public  List<Tab> Tabs { get; set; }
    IUnityContainer container;
    public MainViewModel(IUnityContainer container)
    { 
        this.container=container;
        Tabs = new List<Tab>();
        Tabs.Add(new Tab() { ViewName = "Test1", View = this.container.Resolve<TestView>() });
        Tabs.Add(new Tab() { ViewName = "Test2", View = this.container.Resolve<TestView>() });
        Tabs.Add(new Tab() { ViewName = "Test3", View = this.container.Resolve<TestView>() });
    }
}
```

TestView is a ListView, I want the 3 views have different data. For example, Test1 view has Test1's data and Test2View has Test2's data. But I don't know how to achieve this.

TestViewModel:

```
 public class TestViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Test> Tests{ get; set; }

    public TestViewModel(ITestDataService testDataService)
    {
        Tests= new ObservableCollection<Test>(testDataService.GetTests());
    }
}
```

TestView:

```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Samples}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="8"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Summary}" Margin="8,0,8,8"/>                       
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: How are you binding your DataContext?

Comment: Besides that it looks fine for the most part. My next question would wonder if your IOC is returning singletons?

Comment: Not singleton. I pass the ViewModel to the view's codebegind constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider two alternatives for the issue you mentioned:

- A simple workaround but not completely elegant, would be to rename the **TestView** and create the 3 different Test views, where each one would know what **ViewModel** would bind to its **DataContext**.
- However, on the other hand you could keep the one only generic **TestView** and handle each instance's **DataContext** from the **MainViewModel** constructor. As the **MainViewModel** class is adding all the **TestView** instances into the ***TabList***, that would be the place where **DataContext** of every **TestView** instance would be set. The **MainViewModel** would be responsible for the creation of every **TestView** and the manager of the corresponding **ViewModel's** **DataContext** of the **Views**.

  Therefore, you could resolve the **TestView** instance and set its **DataContext** with the proper **ViewModel** before the NewTab sentences.

As a personal opinion, the second approach may be cleaner. Speccially if a fourth **TestView** would be needed and you would not need to create a new **View** type.

**UPDATE:**

Regarding the second solution of setting the **DataContext** in the **MainViewModel**, the code may look as follows:

```
public  class MainViewModel
{
   public  List<Tab> Tabs { get; set; }
   IUnityContainer container;
   public MainViewModel(IUnityContainer container)
   { 
       this.container = container;
    
       TestView view1 = this.container.Resolve<TestView>();
       view1.DataContext = this.container.Resolve<Test1ViewModel>(); 
       TestView view2 = this.container.Resolve<TestView>();
       view2.DataContext = this.container.Resolve<Test2ViewModel>();
       TestView view3 = this.container.Resolve<TestView>();
       view3.DataContext = this.container.Resolve<Test3ViewModel>();

       Tabs = new List<Tab>();
       Tabs.Add(new Tab() { ViewName = "Test1", View = view1 });
       Tabs.Add(new Tab() { ViewName = "Test2", View = view2 });
       Tabs.Add(new Tab() { ViewName = "Test3", View = view3 });
   }
}
```

As you may see, the concept would be that the **MainViewModel** creates every tab with each **TestView** as described in the question, and it would also manage the configuration of their **DataContext** Property. Taking into account that setting the **DataContext** would be part of the creation of the View, the **MainViewModel** would remain responsible for the complete creation of every **TestView** with its corresponding **DataContext**.

I would like to clarify that the ***ViewModel*** being set on each **DataContext** would be the corresponding **TestViewModel** and not the **MainViewModel** itself. This way, the **MainViewModel** would be able to resolve every Test instance with the specific settings for each **TestView**.

Trying to use a generic *ViewModel* instead, it would also be necessary to configure each instance, which would add more unclean code than just setting the **DataContext**. Based on my understanding, it would be good to encapsulate each Test behavior on different *ViewModels* with descriptive names rather than one generic *ViewModel*.

I hope I have clarified the suggested approach.

Regards.

Comment: The first solution is my current solution, I think it is not elegant too, so looking for another solution. With your second solution, the DataSource should be in the MainViewModel, it seems not elegant too, it should belongs to the TestViewModel. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Allen Li. I have just updated my answer with a detailed description for the second approach. Basically, I set the corresponding DataContext of each TestView instance when MainViewModel instantiates them in order to perform a complete creation and configuration. Each DataContext would correspond to its related TestViewModel that defines the proper configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I do 100% understand your question but I give it a try.

```
ObservableCollection<Test1Value> data1 = new ObservableCollection<Test1Value>(new Test1Value[]
{
    new Test1Value("Location1", 23.5),
    new Test1Value("Location2", 52.5),
    new Test1Value("Location3", 85.2)

});
ObservableCollection<Test2Value> data2 = new ObservableCollection<Test2Value>(new Test2Value[]
{
    new Machine("Machine1", "OK"),
    new Machine("Machine2", "not OK"),
    new Machine("Machine3", "OK"),
    new Machine("Machine4", "open")
});
CompositeCollection coll = new CompositeCollection();
coll.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = data1 });
coll.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = data2 });
Data = coll;

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Test1Value}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" ("/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessuredValue}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=")"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Test2Value}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Machine}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

You can solve this with 1 `viewmodel` which holds different collections of different test values. 
With binding it to a CompositeCollection the ListView or ItemsControl will pick up the right view (data template) for the right class (model).

Find more infos on the CompositeCollection here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx

Or look at how to bind a How do you bind a CollectionContainer to a collection in a view model? here: [How do you bind a CollectionContainer to a collection in a view model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446699/how-do-you-bind-a-collectioncontainer-to-a-collection-in-a-view-model/6446923#6446923)

I think you need to transfer this to prism but the concept should work the same way... =)...

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the types in the two collections are same, so I could not set two DataTemplate for Test1Value and Test2Value.