# Custom ItemsControl with optional Paging

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a slightly extraordinary request ;-)

I'd like to develop an ItemsControl with a "Previous" Control and a "Next" Control. Like this bound to an arbitrary ViewModel:

```
<controls:PagedItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="5" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="system:String">
            <Border Background="Gray" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <controls:PagedItemsControl.PreviousControl>
        <Button Content="Previous" Command="{Binding PreviousCommand}" />
    </controls:PagedItemsControl.PreviousControl>
    <controls:PagedItemsControl.NextControl>
        <Button Content="Next" Command="{Binding NextCommand}" />
    </controls:PagedItemsControl.NextControl>
</controls:PagedItemsControl>
```

In the example I passed 2 buttons controlled by the ViewModel's commands. It would be awesome if somebody could tell me how to listen to the `Control.IsEnable` state and show the `PreviousControl` as first item if enable and the the `NextControl` as last item if enable.

[image: Example Paged ItemsControl]

Thank you

Comment: You need a `CollectionView` (probably a `CompositeCollection` too since your Previous and Next elements are going to be a different type than the rest of the items), and a `RoutedCommand` to handle the execution of the previous / next logic and enabling/disabling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following XAML. We cannot add elements to ItemsPanel while using ItemsSource. But we may try to build a tricky collection which consists of ItemsSource and additional elements. Unfortunately CollectionContainer unable to bound to Items directly. Lucky that good guys already found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446699/how-do-you-bind-a-collectioncontainer-to-a-collection-in-a-view-model) for this case.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock Name="TrickyBinder"
                Tag="{Binding Items}"
                Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="5" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="system:String">
                <Border Background="Gray" Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <CollectionContainer>
                    <CollectionContainer.Collection>
                        <col:ArrayList>
                            <Button Content="Previous" Command="{Binding PreviousCommand}" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEnabled,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        </col:ArrayList>
                    </CollectionContainer.Collection>
                </CollectionContainer>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Path=Tag,Source={x:Reference TrickyBinder}}"/>
                <CollectionContainer>
                    <CollectionContainer.Collection>
                        <col:ArrayList>
                            <Button Content="Next" Command="{Binding NextCommand}" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEnabled,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        </col:ArrayList>
                    </CollectionContainer.Collection>
                </CollectionContainer>
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, looks great. A slight improvement:
Provide `<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemCollection" Source="{Binding Items}"/>` as ressource and use `<CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemCollection}}"/>` instead of your "TrickyBinder"

Comment: @Marcel agree. I wasn't sure that Binding will work properly so I used the most obvious way. Anyway, my example is just a concept ;)