# Add an empty item to a bounded combobox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, model-binding

I need to add an empty item in a bounded combobox within wpf mvvm application, I tried this

```
<ComboBox TabIndex="23"  Text="{Binding Specialisation}" DisplayMemberPath="refsp_libelle">
      <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                          <CompositeCollection >
                                        <ComboBoxItem  > </ComboBoxItem>
                                        <CollectionContainer  Collection="{Binding SpecialisationItemSource}" ></CollectionContainer>
                       </CompositeCollection>

     </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
  </ComboBox>
```

It worked before I tried to add the empty item.

```
<ComboBox TabIndex="23" Text="{Binding Specialisation}" ItemsSource="{Binding SpecialisationItemSource}" DisplayMemberPath="refsp_libelle"/>
```

So I need to know :

1. What is The error that I made?
2. How can I fix it?

thanks,

Comment: MVVM: Model provides a list (`List`), ViewModel adds blank item to it (`List` + `default()` -> `ObservableCollection`) which is then appears in the View (normal binding). [`CompositeCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection(v=vs.100).aspx) (check sample on msdn) is used to bind static collections into one. Normal bindings is [tricky](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6446923/1997232).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why does your approach not work?**

You use `{Binding SpecialisationItemSource}` which, since no source for the binding is explicitly defined, falls back to using target's `DataContext` as the source - or rather it would if `CollectionContainer` was a `FrameworkElement`, and it's not. Hence the source for the binding is `null` and no items show up in the combo. You'd need to set the `Source` property of the binding explicitly to make it work (setting `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` wouldn't work either).

*Actually even if* `CollectionContainer` *was a* `FrameworkElement` *it still would not work, because* `CompositeCollection` *is not a* `FrameworkElement` *(it's not even a* `DependencyObject` *), so the data context inheritance would be broken).*

**How to fix it?**

In order to use the "implicit binding", you can place a `CollectionViewSource` in a resource dictionary, and use that to fill the collection container by using `StaticResource` extension:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Items" Source="{Binding SpecialisationItemSource}" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <TextBlock />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Items}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Notice that I used `Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Items}}"` instead of just `Collection="{StaticResource Items}"` - that's because an object of type `CollectionViewSource` is not an actual collection and is not valid value for the `CollectionContainer.Collection` property, and binding mechanism is designed to turn it into an actual collection. Also, I replaced an empty `ComboBoxItem` with an empty `TextBlock`, because the former resulted in binding errors, which I really don't like seeing. Ultimately, I'd even go with replacing it with a default value for the bound collection's item type.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "not a Framework element".

Comment: @Vidar I mean't it does not derive from [`FrameworkElement` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement?view=netframework-4.8).