# C# WPF: ItemsControl with Add-Content Button

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I want to implement an ItemsControl with a button that adds the same content with another ViewModel. So far I have this code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Controls:ItemView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The button should always be the last item in the control and it should have only one add button. Does anyone have a good solution? I could do it on my own with ugly workarounds but I hate ugly workarounds :)

Comment: So you want a button that will add an element to `Items` ?

Comment: Basically yes, but my main problem is that I don't know how to add a button to the Itemscontrol that is always on the bottom and exists just one time.

Comment: Perhaps you need to use a compositecollection ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446699/how-do-you-bind-a-collectioncontainer-to-a-collection-in-a-view-model

Comment: Why not just leave the button outside of the ItemsControl ? When you click on the `button`, you add the element to `Items` and it will be displyed by the `ItemsControl`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to customize the `Template` of your `ItemsControl` in order to add the `Button` below the `ItemsPresenter`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Controls:ItemView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <StackPanel>
                <ItemsPresenter />
                <Button Content="Add Item"  Click="AddItem_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>

</ItemsControl>
```