# WPF combobox binding from 2 source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm new to binding.

I have `ObservableCollection<MyClass> Classes` binded to `ComboBox.`

I would like to bind to this `ComboBox` also my: `string DefaultString = "Empty"` because I cant (and I dont want to) add it to my collection.

Sth like this:

|---------|

### -Empmty

And after changes:

|---------|

### -Empty

### -Class1

It's possible to do it in xaml, like two bindings to one element? What I should be looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I should be looking for?

The [CompositeCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

**How to: Implement a CompositeCollection:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742405(v=vs.110).aspx

[How do you bind a CollectionContainer to a collection in a view model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446699/how-do-you-bind-a-collectioncontainer-to-a-collection-in-a-view-model)